# Scroll view not scrolling android

Tags: java, android

i tried creating a small game cards game if the first layout the player chooses the character 
but the screen not big enough to fit all the characters "3" i tried to set scrollview horizontally to  fill parent then specific amount then wrap content  but i'm getting tired

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_width="650dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="650dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        >


            <RadioGroup

                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <RadioButton 
                android:id="@+id/RBarthu_mage"
                android:button="@drawable/user_arthu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <RadioButton 
                android:id="@+id/RBDwemer_fighter"
                android:button="@drawable/xuser_dwemer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                />
                            <RadioButton 
                android:id="@+id/RBZombie"
                android:button="@drawable/xuser_zombie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: i have two different scroll view but both not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<LinearLayout` change the line

```
...layout_height="350dp"
```

to

```
...layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Note: And just for good practice, change your width of the `<LinearLayout` to `match_parent`.